# Ansible check remote hosts and include results in email

Tags: linux, windows, email, ansible

How do i get ansible to check remote windows hosts that may require patching (auto-downloaded already, just waiting install), then the results in the body of an email it will send?  The windows check and email bit work but cannot seem to be able to loop the output in the email body?  What i'd like to see in email body:

"Server 1" Requires "2023-04 Cumulative Update for Server 2019"
"Server 2" Requires "2023-04 Cumulative Update for Server 2019"
"Server 3" Requires "2023-04 Cumulative Update for Server 2019"
etc....

this is my play:

```yaml
- hosts: all
  name: check patching
  gather_facts: 'no'
  tasks:
    - name: Get list
      win_shell: >-
        (New-Object -ComObject
        Microsoft.Update.Session).CreateupdateSearcher().Search(“IsHidden=0 and
        IsInstalled=0”).Updates | Select-Object Title
      register: List
- hosts: localhost
  tasks:
    - name: mail out
      host: 1.1.1.1
      port: 25
      from: SomeEmail@Somewhere.com
      to: SomeEmail@SomewhereElse.com
      subject: patches
      body: '(( hostvars[''????''][''List''].stdout_lines }}'
```

What do i need to do in that body line to present a list of hosts and patches required in the email?  The '????' as i'm not sure how to do this?

I.e

```
"Server 1" Requires "2023-04 Cumulative Update for Server 2019"
"Server 2" Requires "2023-04 Cumulative Update for Server 2019"
"Server 3" Requires "2023-04 Cumulative Update for Server 2019"
etc....
```

Comment: Please double check and provide a valid playbook. The above will fire an error before ansible even tries to run it. It isn't valid yaml to start with (check the indentation) and your last task does not have a valid module to run anyway.

Comment: I suggest you look at the `template` module to create the file you want (use `delegate_to: localhost` and `run_once: yes`) based on the values in `List`.  Then email file as the content.

Comment: Zeitounator -- It does run - i had to manually dictate that in as its not an internet facing system. I've now ran it through YAML Lint to make sure it complies.  For ref its ran from AWX, and all works except the body section of the email - cant figure out how to loop through the results in that body section.

Comment: @user3266154 Thank you comments are considered as fluff on SO and will be regularly flagged as such for deletion by SO users, as any other comments considered purely conversational. Now regarding `it does run` => https://gist.github.com/zeitounator/db82cbec4e65029df79cf2c23d5b0d49

Comment: @user3266154 Please do not edit questions with solution. Provide a self answer if you feel it deserves it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the partial info on your data structure and the invalid playbook you provided, I think without any warranty you are looking for something like this:

```yaml
- hosts: all
  name: check patching
  gather_facts: 'no'
  tasks:
    - name: Get list
      ansible.windows.win_shell: >-
        (New-Object -ComObject
        Microsoft.Update.Session).CreateupdateSearcher().Search(“IsHidden=0 and
        IsInstalled=0”).Updates | Select-Object Title
      register: patch_list

    - name: mail out
      vars:
        mail_body: "{{ ansible_play_hosts | map('extract', hostvars)
          | map(attribute='patch_list.stdout') | join('\\n') }}"
      community.general.mail:
        host: 1.1.1.1
        port: 25
        from: SomeEmail@Somewhere.com
        to: SomeEmail@SomewhereElse.com
        subject: patches
        body: "{{ mail_body }}"
      delegate_to: localhost
      run_once: true
```